# Duplicates in E-Mail notification

Tags: bug, status-completed, email-notification

I just got a notification about a comment that looked like this:

[image]

The entries all have the same time stamp.

However, the [question in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454693/exif-read-data-is-not-working-in-php-5-1-6#comment15118407_11454693) has only one comment.

In my mind, this can't have been the OP creating and deleting his comment repeatedly, because they all have the same time stamp and there would have to have been a 15 second pause in between new entries. Right?

Just in case this is a symptom of something.

Comment: We just *really* wanted you to know about that comment.  We're looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something went a bit... sidewise in our serialization of inbox items.  Lots of accidental duplicates (but only for some people).

Oddly enough, the only place this error becomes visible is in the emails.  Everywhere else we're using data structures that de-dupe just by accident.  Emails has a wonderful Accounts to InboxItems join that sort of goes to hell.

This has been "fixed" (underlying cause is still being looked into, but the dupe data is prevented from being created).

Comment: Status-"Completed"

Comment: @BenBrocka status-"working on your problems".

Comment: I think that bug [left some nasty traces](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153300/inbox-tab-of-network-profile-shows-same-comment-multiple-time) :)

Comment: @KevinMontrose - The bug is not resolved. [I can still see some comments multiple times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153300/187824)

Comment: @hims056 well, it's a different bug. This one here is about the email having duplicates and yours is about the global inbox. Will vote to reopen and flag your report for better chance of reopening it.